# How to disable "Locate" button on install4j Wizard and display custom message for no JRE found situation?

Tags: install4j

I am trying to create an installer without bundled JRE that will display a message telling users to download proper JRE from java.com instead of asking them to locate JRE when the installer cannot find suitable JRE, but I wasn't able to find anything that will allow me to do this.

I tried to add Screen or add Action in Installer's Startup sequence, but both of them are only executed after the install4j Wizard has located suitable JRE or ask the users to locate suitable JRE or ask users to download JRE (dynamic bundling).

Any insight on this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is in the native part of the installer before the JVM is loaded, so adding a screen or an action does not help because they are executed in the JVM.

You can change the error message by going to General Settings->Languages, define a custom localization file and override the message:

exe4j.NoJvmFound=Your message telling the user to go to java.com.

Comment: Thank you Ingo, that was what I needed; however, is it possible to modify a system variable so that the "Locate" button will not show up?

Comment: @L.C. Unfortunately this is not possible at this time